# Not getting any error but image is not getting displayed in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, neural-network, image-recognition

I trying to develop a program using neural network to solve any real-life problem.
so, I took retinopathy detection using Probabilistic neural network using MATLAB. I took some help from professor and developed the program. I have trained the neural network and created the dataset but when testing the my neural network I m not getting output...
I m new to MATLAB and this is the 1st program I wrote in MATLAB .

I have created training dataset and providing an input image to get the affected area

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
img=imread('nor4.jpg');
m=impixel(img);
dlmwrite('D:\Retinopathy detection\Training.csv',m,'-append');
%figure(1),imshow(img);
```

---CODE FOR ACTUCAL IMPLEMENTATION---

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
fileID = fopen('Training.csv');
C = textscan(fileID,'%f%f%f%f','Delimiter',',');
fclose(fileID);
x=[C{1} C{2} C{3}];
t=[C{4}];
s=input('Enter spread : ');
net = newpnn(x',t',s);
img=imread('trr.jpg');
[m,n,p]=size(img);
R=img(:,:,1);
G=img(:,:,2);
B=img(:,:,3);
RR=reshape(R,m*n,1);
GG=reshape(G,m*n,1);
BB=reshape(B,m*n,1);
Xtest=double([RR GG BB]);
Y = sim(net,Xtest');
Im=reshape(Y,m,n);
for i=1:1:m
    for j=1:1:n
        if Im(i,j)==1
            Newimg(i,j,:)=[230,166,122];
        else 
            Newimg(i,j,:)=img(i,j,:);
        end
    end 
end
figure(1),imshow(img);
figure(2),imshow(Newimg);`
```

when I run this program ..I should get two image window one with input image and second window will have the retinopathy detected area ..

but when I run the program, I m getting on image window correct but...on the second window, am only getting green color or if I change the value ill get different color….

can you please help me out with this I m really stuck !! I m not getting help from my professor.

Comment: `dlmwrite` writes 3 columns of RGB data to the CSV file, but `textscan` reads 4 columns back from the CSV file resulting in `t` being a vector of `NaNs`. Is this what you intended? Consider using `writematrix` and `readmatrix` instead.

Comment: I'll implement your idea sir!! Will tell if something happens.. thanks 

Answer (score 0):

imshow with double data assumes that the data is in the range [0,1] for purposes of mapping your data to a color.

Try:

```
imshow(mat2gray(Newimg));
```

Which will rescale your data to the range [0,1] before displaying it.

Comment: Still getting the same output!!  Newimg(i,j,:)=[230,166,122]; error is on this line I think soo!!